# inexplicable high cpu percentage on azure hosting plan

Tags: azure

I currently have 4 websites hosted in a S2 hosting plan and this evening received a CPU percentage alert. I went to the management portal and checked all of the sites hosted in the hosting plan, however found no reason for it to be so high. After checking site by site and finding no evidence of what could be causing this problem I went and stopped every site, much to my surprise the CPU usage did not drop and it's been a staggering 50% for the last 30 minutes, **is there any way to find out what is causing this? Do you guys have any idea if it could be a bug in the azure sites service?**

[image: Here's a SS of the CPU Percentage, Http Queue Length and memo]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Contact Azure support?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of things to check for:
 - do you have any webjobs on that system? They also consume resources but don't show up in all reports.

You can also check the Kudu Process Monitor to see if there are any other processes running (maybe you've been hacked and someone is running something on your box?) If you've never used the Kudu tool, it is quite handy - to get to it in your browser, put '.scm' after the sitename in your url. For example, if your site is

```
    'mysite.azurewebsites.net'
```

the Kudu tools are at

```
    'mysite.scm.azurewebsites.net'
```

There is a process explorer in there that you can see what processes are running under your account.

Comment: Restarting the web apps solved the problem for me, seems like it was a bug in azure which was solved quite a few months ago. Thanks for your response anyway!